# Dataspell notebook Jupyter not installed (macos)

Tags: macos, jupyter-notebook, dataspell

I run DataSpell on a macOS device and when I open a notebook from a local directory that I have in workspace, over the notebook there is the message

> Jupyter is not installed

The configured interpreter for the notebook is in a conda virtual environment in which I have installed Jupyter notebook.

The Jupyter server is on localhost 8888.

Also, when I run a cell with `Pytorch` code that calls a `PyTorch` build in model, for example `nn.GRU`, the cell starts running but never finishes.

Any idea what is wrong?